# Can I generate a BUILD file in Bazel?

Tags: go, build, bazel

I want to use the go lint tool to generate a BUILD file for bazel.

I would have a go binary that would perform something like this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF > BUILD
# THIS FILE IS AUTOGENERATED

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("//go:def.bzl", "go_prefix", "go_library", "go_binary", "go_test")
EOF

for pkg in `go list -f {{.ImportPath}} ./...`; do
    go list -f "`cat test.in`" $pkg >> "BUILD";
done

buildifier -mode fix BUILD
```

The test.in file contains:

```
{{ if eq .Name "main" }}
go_binary
{{else}}
go_library
{{end}}
("{{.Name}}",
    srcs=[
        {{range .GoFiles}}
            "{{.}}",
        {{end}} 
    ],
    deps=[
        {{range .Imports}}
            "{{.}}",
        {{end}} 
    ],
    csrcs=[
        {{range .CgoFiles}}
            "{{.}}",
        {{end}} 
    ],
    swig_srcs=[
        {{range .SwigFiles}}
            "{{.}}",
        {{end}} 
    ],
    cxxswig=[
        {{range .SwigCXXFiles}}
            "{{.}}",
        {{end}} 
    ],
    cflags=[
        {{range .CgoCFLAGS}}
            "{{.}}",
        {{end}} 
    ],
    cxxflags=[
        {{range .CgoCXXFLAGS}}
            "{{.}}",
        {{end}} 
    ],
    cppflags=[
        {{range .CgoCPPFLAGS}}
            "{{.}}",
        {{end}} 
    ],           
    {{ with $ctx := context}}
        {{$ctx.InstallSuffix}}
    {{end}}    
)
```

And this generates:

```
# THIS FILE IS AUTOGENERATED

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("//go:def.bzl", "go_prefix", "go_library", "go_binary", "go_test")

go_library

(
    "tensorflow",
    srcs = [
        "doc.go",
        "gen.go",
        "graph.go",
        "session.go",
    ],
    deps = [
        "C",
        "encoding/binary",
        "fmt",
        "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto",
        "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/proto",
        "math",
        "reflect",
        "runtime",
        "strings",
        "unsafe",
    ],
    csrcs = [
        "lib.go",
        "tensor.go",
    ],
    swig_srcs = [
    ],
    cxxswig = [
        "tensorflow.swigcxx",
    ],
    cflags = [
        "-I/Users/fmilo/workspace/gopath/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/../../../",
    ],
    cxxflags = [
        "-I/Users/fmilo/workspace/gopath/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/../../../",
        "-std=c++11",
    ],
    cppflags = [
    ],
)

go_library

(
    "tensorflow",
    srcs = [
        "allocation_description.pb.go",
        "attr_value.pb.go",
        "config.pb.go",
        "cost_graph.pb.go",
        "device_attributes.pb.go",
        "event.pb.go",
        "function.pb.go",
        "graph.pb.go",
        "kernel_def.pb.go",
        "log_memory.pb.go",
        "master.pb.go",
        "memmapped_file_system.pb.go",
        "meta_graph.pb.go",
        "named_tensor.pb.go",
        "op_def.pb.go",
        "queue_runner.pb.go",
        "saved_tensor_slice.pb.go",
        "saver.pb.go",
        "step_stats.pb.go",
        "summary.pb.go",
        "tensor.pb.go",
        "tensor_description.pb.go",
        "tensor_shape.pb.go",
        "tensor_slice.pb.go",
        "tensorflow_server.pb.go",
        "test_log.pb.go",
        "tf_ops_def.go",
        "types.pb.go",
        "variable.pb.go",
        "versions.pb.go",
        "worker.pb.go",
    ],
    deps = [
        "fmt",
        "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto",
        "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any",
        "math",
    ],
    csrcs = [
    ],
    swig_srcs = [
    ],
    cxxswig = [
    ],
    cflags = [
    ],
    cxxflags = [
    ],
    cppflags = [
    ],
)

go_library

(
    "tensorflow_error",
    srcs = [
        "error_codes.pb.go",
    ],
    deps = [
        "fmt",
        "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto",
        "math",
    ],
    csrcs = [
    ],
    swig_srcs = [
    ],
    cxxswig = [
    ],
    cflags = [
    ],
    cxxflags = [
    ],
    cppflags = [
    ],
)

go_library

(
    "tensorflow_grpc",
    srcs = [
        "master_service.pb.go",
        "worker_service.pb.go",
    ],
    deps = [
        "fmt",
        "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto",
        "math",
        "tensorflow/core/protobuf",
    ],
    csrcs = [
    ],
    swig_srcs = [
    ],
    cxxswig = [
    ],
    cflags = [
    ],
    cxxflags = [
    ],
    cppflags = [
    ],
)
```

of course the above BUILD file does not work yet, but I want to make sure first that the approach that I am pursuing is valid.

- How can I specify a pre-BUILD phase in bazel ?
- is it possible?

Comment: What we generally do at Google is to manually run the code generator when you need it (it can also be automated in the IDE), and check in the output in the source control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you cannot generate BUILD files, they must be there at the beginning of the build.  Bazel's general build phases are:

- Parse the targets you specified on the command line.
- Look up BUILD files in each directory those specify.
- Parse BUILD files that those targets mention (and so on).
- Generate a tree of actions to execute (e.g., "Run shell script").
- Actually execute the actions.

So, by the time your script is executed, the time for reading BUILD files is long over.

Also, outputs are put in their own directory (under bazel-out) so they wouldn't even be present in your source tree without munging.

That said...

Skylark remote repositories do let you execute code to write files, including BUILD files, in other repositories.  So you could, theoretically, have something like (untested):

```
def _gen_repo_impl(repo_ctx):
  # Writes external/reponame/BUILD
  repo_ctx.execute("/your/bash/script.sh")
  for path in repo_ctx.attr.paths:
    repo_ctx.symlink(path, path.basename)

generated_repo = repository_rule(
    implementation = _gen_repo_impl,
    attrs = {"paths": attr.label_list(allow_files = True)}
)
```

Then in your WORKSPACE file, do something like:

```
load('//path/to/your:genrepo.bzl', 'generated_repo')
generated_repo(
    name = "pwd",
    paths = ["src", "test", "third_party"],
)
```

Then you could build/depend on `@pwd//...` and the repository rule would generate an external repo with symlinks to src, test, and third_party (theoretically... my code's probably got some typos).

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if this is an accepted behavior for bazel projects ? are there any downsides?

Comment: I mean, it's a little hacky and fragile (you're manually specifying directories that might change).

Comment: Why do Skylark remote repositories allow this? What is the intended use?

Comment: @JosephGarvin to be able to support 3rd party packages/repositories that do not have BUILD files (e.g. including a header from a downloaded zip file)

Answer (score 1):

Following Python script generates a BAZEL build file for C++ files in one directory. We're extending this to finding related libraries and automatic creating a BAZEL tree of BUILD files. If we get enough likes, this may be published here. Feel free to adapt the script to other languages.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
@file: create_bazel.py

Created on 22 jan 2022

@brief:  Create bazel file of current directory.
@author: mensfort
'''

import os

class Bazel:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getFiles(self):
        self.sources = []
        self.includes = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
            for name in files:
                if name.lower().endswith(".cpp"):
                    self.sources.append(name)
                if name.lower().endswith('.hpp'):
                    self.includes.append(name)
                if name.lower().endswith('.h'):
                    self.includes.append(name)

    def getName(self):
        self.path = os.getcwd()
        self.baseName = os.path.basename(self.path)

    def run(self):
        self.getFiles()
        self.getName()
        self.createFile()

    def createFile(self):
        f = open('BUILD', 'w')
        f.write('# %s\n' % (self.path))
        f.write('\n')
        f.write('package(default_testonly = False,\n')
        f.write('        default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])\n')
        f.write('\n')
        f.write('cc_library(\n')
        f.write('    name = "%s",\n' % (self.baseName))
        f.write('     visibility =[ "//visibility:public"],\n')
        f.write('     srcs = [\n')
        for x in self.sources:
            f.write('        "%s",\n' % (x))
        f.write('    ],\n')
        f.write('    hdrs = [\n')
        for x in self.includes:
            f.write('        "%s",\n' % (x))
        f.write('    ],\n')
        f.write('    copts = [\n')
        f.write('    ],\n')
        f.write('    deps = [\n')
        f.write('    ]\n')
        f.write(')\n')
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Bazel()
    x.run()
    print("BAZEL file created!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I think we can create a custom rule and run before the build progress.

Below is an example of a builder, we can refer to

1. BUILD.bazel typically in the workspace root:

```
load("@com_github_bazelbuild_buildtools//buildifier:def.bzl", "buildifier")

buildifier(
    name = "buildifier",
)
```

2. Invoke with

```
bazel run //:buildifier
```

we can use a custom rule to replace it and achieve the same functionality!