# Bazel unable to build go targets (version 1.21) due to new workspace mode

Tags: go, bazel, go-work

**What version of rules_go are you using?**

0.42.0

**What version of gazelle are you using?**

0.33.0

**What version of Bazel are you using?**

6.4.0

**Does this issue reproduce with the latest releases of all the above?**

yes

**What operating system and processor architecture are you using?**

MacOS Sonoma / Apple M2 Pro

**What did you do?**

upgraded to go 1.21, now when I run `bazel build //...` , all of the external go modules my program utilizes throws errors related to the new workspace mode introduced in 1.18 https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces:

[image]

How do i resolve this? there is no feasible way to add all the modules used in that directory to a `go.work` file. Is there a way to turn this new workspace mode off?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the error message is:

```bash
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ - /9b1e5e83eabb1d6e19b3164cad07defe/external/com_github_klosmo_atlas_app_toolkit_v2/rpc/errfields/BUILD.bazel:18:11: GoCompilePkg external/com github_klosmo_atlas_app_toolkit_v2/rpc/errfields/errfields.a failed: (Exit 1): builder failed: error executing command (from target @com_github_klosmo_atlas_app_toolkit_v2//rpc/errfields:errfields) bazel-out/d&rwin_arm64-opt=exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/go_sdk/builder_reset/builder compilepkg -sdk external/go_sdk -installsuffix darwin_arm64 -src (remaining 21 arguments skipped)
Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
external/com_github_klosmo_atlas_app_toolkit v2/rpc/errfields/error_fields.go:7:10: undefined: FieldInfo
external/com_github_klosmo_atlas.app_toolkit_v2/rpc/errfields/error.fields.go:9:26; undefined: StringListValue
external/com_github_klosmo_atlas_app_toolkit_v2/rpc/errfields/error_fields.go:13:23: undefined: StringListValue
external/com_github_klosmo_atlas app_toolkit_v2/rpc/errfields/error_fields.go:20:11: undefined: FieldInfo
external/com_github_klosmo_atlas_app_toolkit_v2/rpc/errfields/error_fields.go:39:11: undefined: FieldInfo
compilepkg: error running subcommand external/go sdk/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/compile: exit status 2
INFO: Elapsed time: 31.451s, Critical
```

That points to a compilation failure in a Bazel build targeting a Go package from the `com_github_klosmo_atlas_app_toolkit_v2` repository.
The error messages specifically mention undefined identifiers like `FieldInfo` and `StringListValue` within the `errfields` package. That indicates that there might be missing dependencies or incorrect import paths in the code.

> No, the issue isn't pulling in the target repo, the problem is that Bazel symlinks repos to the `/private/var/tmp/_bazel_/external/` directory and builds all targets from there - and with the advent of go workspaces, these are deemed as external modules to my project; Thus throwing the errors because I am not using a `go.work` file to reference these 'external' modules...
>
> I can't possibly reference every single go module manually in this fashion, so I was wondering if there was a workaround for this"

So the issue comes from the interaction between [Go's new workspace mode](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces#create-the-workspace) and the way Bazel handles external dependencies by symlinking them into a separate directory (the [`outputRoot` directory](https://bazel.build/remote/output-directories)). This behavior causes Go to treat these dependencies as external modules, which in turn triggers errors when a `go.work` file is not used to reference these modules.

As a workaround, you might consider creating a script that sets up the necessary symlinks from your Bazel build directory to your Go workspace, mimicking the layout expected by Go's workspace mode.
This script could be run as a pre-build step (a bit like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38358504/6309), about the bazel pre-build step).

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ln -s /private/var/tmp/_bazel_/external/ /path/to/your/go/workspace
bazel build //...
```

Or, you could automate the generation of a `go.work` file based on the dependencies specified in your `go.mod` file or Bazel build files. This script could scan your project for dependencies, and auto-generate a `go.work` file that references all required modules.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Script to generate go.work file based on dependencies
# for instance, using go list -m all

# Define the output go.work file
gowork_file="./go.work"

# Create or clear the output go.work file
echo "go 1.18" > $gowork_file

# Get the list of module dependencies from the current project
deps=$(go list -m all | tail -n +2)

# Write the module dependencies to the go.work file
echo "" >> $gowork_file
echo "require (" >> $gowork_file
for dep in $deps; do
    echo "    $dep" >> $gowork_file
done
echo ")" >> $gowork_file

# Output the generated go.work file to the console
cat $gowork_file
```

Since `bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle` has a "very minimalistic support for go workspaces" ([PR 1250](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/pull/1250)), that could help.

Comment: no, the issue isn't pulling in the target repo, the problem is that Bazel symlinks repos to the `/private/var/tmp/_bazel_/external/` directory and builds all targets from there - and with the advent of go workspaces, these are deemed as external modules to my project; Thus throwing the errors because I am not using a `go.work` file to reference these 'external' modules... I can't possibly reference every single go module manually in this fashion so I was wondering if there was a workaround for this.

Comment: @JohnJackson OK, I have amended the answer to address your comment.